# Silver Efex Pro competitors

Tags: black-and-white, software-recommendation

I have been trying Silver Efex Pro the last two weeks with absolutely amazing results. But before I commit my $$$ I would like to know if there is any other similar software out there that can do the same thing.

I have just heard of Macphun Tonality but it's only available for Mac and I'm a Windows user.

PS. I already use Photoshop and Lightroom and I still prefer Silver Efex Pro for B&W processing.

Comment: Topaz has a good B&W plugin.  I think OnOne has one now too.  I think all have free trials.  Really a personal choice, but Silver Efex really seems to be the gold standard - I don't think I've ever seen a review where it wasn't the preferred option over other products.

Comment: Silver Efex is OK, interface is a bit odd, you don't have brushes and you don't have RAW support. It's a great tool to be used with Photoshop, but on its own it lacks some features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other options include:

- onOne Software Perfect B&W 9 - http://www.ononesoftware.com/products/bw9/
- Topaz B&W Effects 2 - http://www.topazlabs.com/bweffects

Outdoor Photographer recently did a B&W special and had an article that touched on the software:  http://www.outdoorphotographer.com/gear/more-gear/b-and-w-essentials.html?start=2#.VBGuUPldUep

Silver Efex Pro is definitely the market leader, but there is no doubt that you can getting stunning results from any of these three options.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'll give these a try. Curiously enough the day after I posted my question I started receiving email from onOne software but I cannot remember ever having heard of then before or having ever registered to their site... Humm... :-/